# Extracting dataframe rows in groups before specific row?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some event log data I need to reshape:

| Timestamp | Event | SID | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-15 10:35 | OPEN | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 10:37 | OPEN | 8022822 | user1 |
| 2021-04-15 10:37 | OPEN | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 10:41 | OPEN | 1234567 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 10:45 | OPEN | 1234567 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 11:39 | OPEN | 8022822 | user1 |
| 2021-04-15 11:59 | DO | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 12:24 | OPEN | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 12:59 | DO | 8022822 | user1 |
| 2021-04-15 13:25 | OPEN | 8022822 | user1 |
| 2021-04-15 13:29 | OPEN | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 14:27 | OPEN | 8022822 | user1 |

For each user that does a `DO` operation on every `SID` I need to find the prior `OPEN` event.

Desired outcome:

| Timestamp | Event | SID | User |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-15 10:37 | OPEN | 7933711 | user2 |
| 2021-04-15 11:39 | OPEN | 8022822 | user1 |

I can get the groups I need using

```
grouped = sorted.groupby(['SID', 'User']).filter(lambda x: (x['Event']=='DO').any())
```

but I can't get the next part to extract the `OPEN` event before the `DO` event. I've looked at using [`asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html) but I don't know pandas well enough.

My code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import sys

eventLogPath = 'test3.csv'

evTimeStamps_df = pd.read_csv(eventLogPath)

evTimeStamps_df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime( evTimeStamps_df['Timestamp'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
evTimeStamps_df.Event = pd.Categorical(evTimeStamps_df.Event, ['OPEN', 'DO'], ordered=True)

sorted = evTimeStamps_df.sort_values(['Timestamp', 'Event'])

grouped = sorted.groupby(['SID', 'User']).filter(lambda x: (x['Event']=='DO').any())
```

Comment: In the output what logic does `Timestamp` column follow?

Comment: The output timestamp does not need to be sorted. I just need one row per SID so I can join it with another table. But I assumed sorting is needed to get the last OPEN event before any DO event?

Comment: As long as the dataframe is sorted in increasing `Timestamp` (can we assume that, or do we have to explicitly convert it and sort on it?), we don't even need to look at `Timestamp` column. Also, **you have simultaneous `OPEN` events from users 1,2 at `2021-04-15 10:37`. Does the solution need to be able to handle >1 simultaneous previous event?** or just pick the one for that user? or what?

Comment: From your comment *"For each (user, SID) that does a DO operation... I need to find the prior OPEN event."* and the accepted answer, I take it you only want to consider events for that (user, SID). So keep the sort by `Timestamp`, then groupby '(User', SID).

Comment: ...then if you did want to insist on using [`asof()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.asof.html), you could replace `OPEN` valeus with `NaN` and use `asof`. Seems forced though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sorting the `df` and then `shift()` to get the neighboring `OPEN` event:

```py
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp) # if not already datetime

df = df.sort_values(['User', 'Timestamp', 'SID', 'Event'])
df[df.Event.eq('DO').shift().bfill()]

#              Timestamp  Event      SID   User
# 9  2021-04-15 13:25:00   OPEN  8022822  user1
# 7  2021-04-15 12:24:00   OPEN  7933711  user2
```

Comment: Ah, you make it seem so easy! Thanks! Doing the right sort in the first place makes it simple.